# Delete the last 3 versions folders - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory

I have a tree with some software versions and i need to keep the last 3 versions.

I have tree folder like this:

Versions:

Folders:

**'10.7.0.290', '10.7.0.289', '10.7.0.281', '10.7.0.278', '10.7.0.275'**

**'10.6.7.282', '10.6.7.277', '10.6.7.274', '10.6.7.270'**

I want to keep the **last 3** folders of each version for example in this case i want to keep the **last 3** of '10.7.0.yyy' and '10.6.7.xxx version':

**'10.7.0.290', '10.7.0.289', '10.7.0.281'**

**'10.6.7.282', '10.6.7.277', '10.6.7.274'**

and delete this:

**'10.7.0.278', '10.7.0.275'**

**'10.6.7.270'**

but my script are keeping only the last 3 not of each version:

Script:

```
import os
import re
import shutil

versions = []
folders = []
a = os.listdir('.')
a.sort(reverse=True)
sorted(a)

for fn in a:
    folders.append(fn)
    if os.path.isdir(fn):
        version = (re.match('^([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*', fn)).group(1)
        if (version) not in versions:
            versions.append(version)

result = []


for version in versions:
    temp = []
    for folder in folders:
        if folder.startswith(version):
            temp.append(folder)

    result.append(temp)
print result    

for version in result:
   for i in range(max(len(version) - 3, 0)):
       print version[i]
 #   shutil.rmtree(version[i])
```

Result

```
10.7.0.290 #this files are deleted
10.7.0.289 #this files are deleted
10.6.7.282 #this files are deleted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
import os
import shutil

from collections import defaultdict


versions = defaultdict(list)
directories = next(os.walk('.'))[1]
for directory in directories:
    major, minor, patch, minor_patch = directory.split('.')
    versions['{}.{}.{}'.format(major, minor, patch)].append(int(minor_patch))

for version, minor_patches in versions.items():
    minor_patches.sort(reverse=True)
    to_remove = minor_patches[3:]
    for minor_patch in to_remove:
        path = '{}.{}'.format(version, minor_patch)
        shutil.rmtree('./{}'.format(path))
```

Example:

```
[$:/tmp/folders] $ tree
.
├── 10.6.7.270
├── 10.6.7.274
├── 10.6.7.277
├── 10.6.7.282
├── 10.7.0.275
├── 10.7.0.278
├── 10.7.0.281
├── 10.7.0.289
├── 10.7.0.290
└── folders.py

9 directories, 1 file
[$:/tmp/folders] $ python folders.py 
[$:/tmp/folders] $ tree
.
├── 10.6.7.274
├── 10.6.7.277
├── 10.6.7.282
├── 10.7.0.281
├── 10.7.0.289
├── 10.7.0.290
└── folders.py

6 directories, 1 file
```

Comment: i have an error if i have a folder with 10.6.7.274.22 trown an exception and abort... if i have other files in folder with wrong names not xx.yy.zz.aa abort with erro bellow 

ValueError: need more than one value

Answer (score 1):

Let's point down the steps needed.

1. Use `os.listdir` to get a list of all the directories in given path.
2. sort the list and take first 3 directory name by slicing the list
3. use  `shutil.rmtree` to remove them inside a loop.

So, the solution should be:

```
from os import listdir
import shutil

directories_to_delete = sorted(listdir('desired/path'))[:3]
for directory in directories_to_delete:
    shutil.rmtree(directory)
```

Comment: Sorting by strings results version `10` being considered earlier than `9`.

Comment: I've only considered the mentioned input. However, you are quite logical, I will update it soon.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert folder names to lists of `int`. This would allow the correct ordering of the versions so that `10` is considered later than `9`. Then you could sort them in reverse order and use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group them based on 3 first components. Then for each group you could discard first 3 items with [`dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) and delete the rest:

```
from itertools import groupby, dropwhile

FOLDERS = [
    '10.7.0.290', '10.7.0.289', '10.7.0.281', '10.7.0.278', '10.7.0.275',
    '10.6.7.282', '10.6.7.277', '10.6.7.274', '10.6.7.270'
]

components = ([int(x) for x in fn.split('.')] for fn in FOLDERS)
for _, g in groupby(sorted(components, reverse=True), key=lambda x: x[:3]):
    for _, fn in dropwhile(lambda x: x[0] < 3, enumerate(g)):
        print 'Remove {}'.format('.'.join(str(x) for x in fn))
```

Output:

```
Remove 10.7.0.278
Remove 10.7.0.275
Remove 10.6.7.270
```

Comment: Actually I've misunderstood the question, your's one is correct, upvoted.